# Как загрузить картинку в модель по ссылке в этой же модели?

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

Я новичек в django и в программировании вообще, заранее извиняюсь за некорректность вопроса. 
И так, есть модель

```
class Gallerys(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    url = models.URLField()
```

В url находится ссылка на картинку. Есть csv файл из которого я загружаю в бд (postgres) около 2000 записей. В django admin все отображается. Мне нужно чтобы картинки по ссылке url скачивались и добавлялись в бд, чтобы в представлениях я мог с ними работать. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, где вы хотите хранить изображения. Если на сервере с django, а ссылки из csv ведут на стороние ресурсы, то нужно будет заменить url на FileField. Напишите подробнее

Comment: Изображения хранить думаю лучше на сервере. Да, ссылки из csv ведут на сторонние ресурсы. А вообще вся проблема заключается в том, что все эти изображения разного размера и не красиво отображаются. Смысл в том, чтобы часть этих изображений (10 штук) отобразить вместе рядом. А получается верблюд из за размерности изображений.

Comment: этот вопрос уже не по теме, нужен новый вопрос, но скажу, что смотрите в сторону JS плагинов/библиотек или сами через CSS или обработчики меняйте область отображения/размер изображений